# mvc error in url when contain "%" char

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

when I add "%" character to the  mvc url prject  I get bad request from server , how to let such character to be allowed in the url 
I want this to work if possible

http://localhost:56203/Home/gf%test/194/184/w 
if I remove "%" it work fine

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The % character tells the web server that you have an encoded character.  In order to include an actual % character, you need to encode it as %25:

http://localhost:56203/Home/gf%25test/194/184/w

Comment: I tried your solutions and still getting bad request 
also I tried this 
/Home/%2fContentFiles%2fImages%2f2.jpg/194/184/w
and give me the same error

Comment: What purpose does the '%' serve in the URL?  You definitely shouldn't UrlEncode the slashes, unless they're part of a data string.